# Can I configure a @FeignClient url using a properties/yml file with custom property name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openfeign

I want to use @FeignClient to take URL from property on the bases of environment on that it's run. 
**like**: i have `test`, `dev` and `prod`. All these enviroment have different URL for **example** :
`test` : `http://localhost:9000`
`dev`  : `http://localhost:8080`
`prod` : `http://localhost:8181`

```
@FeignClient(name = "my-test-servies", url = "${com.test.my.access.url}")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/authors")
public interface MyFeignClient {
  public List<Author> getAuthors();
}
```

This works but I want the URL property to be changed based on enviroment. As i am using single property file My yml property file is as below : application.yml

```
com:
  prod:
    my:
      access:
        url: "http://localhost:8181"
  test:
    my:
      access:
        url: "http://localhost:9000"
  dev:
    my:
      access:
        url: "http://localhost:8080"
```

Can it be done and if yes; how?

Comment: use profiles and remove the explict call to the env in the properties?

Comment: Profiles are used for this purpose only. Any Specific reason you want to have all properties in singe file ?

Comment: yes, i am using profiles in my other service but i want to use single yml/property file in my service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make an factory.

Edit : `Class<T> clazz` is an Feign interface.

```
public class FeignClientFactory {

    public static <T> T build(final String url, Class<T> clazz) {
        return Feign.builder().client(new OkHttpClient()).logger(new Slf4jLogger(clazz)).logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder()).decoder(new JacksonDecoder()).target(clazz, url);
    }

    public static <T> T build(final String url, Class<T> clazz, ObjectMapper mapper) {
        Assert.notNull(mapper, "The mapper can't be null !");

        return Feign.builder().client(new OkHttpClient()).logger(new Slf4jLogger(clazz)).logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(mapper)).decoder(new JacksonDecoder(mapper)).target(clazz, url);
    }

    public static <T> T buildWithInterceptor(final String url, Class<T> clazz, RequestInterceptor interceptor) {
        return Feign.builder().client(new OkHttpClient()).logger(new Slf4jLogger(clazz)).logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder()).requestInterceptor(interceptor).decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                .target(clazz, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any example link that i can refer ?